# jQuery find element with custom attribute 1 and 2

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, attributes, anchor

I've written this code to load dynamic content:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
  var path = $(this).attr('path')
});
```

and this to create anchor links when the content is loaded:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
window.location.hash = title ;
```

And this part to check which content was loaded:

```
var title = $('.item').attr('title');
if (window.location.href.indexOf(title) > -1) {
  console.log("found it");
}
```

Now I would like to load the content via the anchor link so I need to get an element with the title that fits to the path. The HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div class="item" path="/mainfolder/subfolder/item/" title="I'am the title">
```

Do you have any ideas to do something like that? I just need to know how I'am able to search for elements with: `attribute 1 which has attribute 2`

Thanks for answers guys!

Comment: Don't create custom attributes, use `data-*` attributes.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but see [jQuery attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for $(" *[attr*='title']");

Comment: Why are data-* attributes better then custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to select it ^^

```js
if($('[path="/mainfolder/subfolder/item/"]').length > 0){
  console.log("Found1!");
};
if($('[title="I\'am the title"]').length > 0){
  console.log("Found2!");
};

if($('[path="/mainfolder/subfolder/item/"][title="I\'am the title"]').length > 0){
  console.log("Found3!");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="item" path="/mainfolder/subfolder/item/" title="I'am the title"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and how could I use variables in the if function?

Comment: var name = $('[path="/mainfolder/subfolder/item/"]');

Comment: No, In my case I need to get a element with `path=BlaBliBlub and title=FasMasKas ` because I got around 50 elements with different paths and titles. I cant create 1 function for every case.

Comment: function(p,t){ $('[path="' +p + '"][title="' + t + '"]') }

Comment: Looks good, but could u explain me a little bit what the p, t is?

Comment: names of variables that you will pass to the function

Comment: So I have to create the variables first? In others words, I have to define the variables p and t before I use the function, right?